# VBA, Autofilter Criteria Not Equal to #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autofilter my data to not equal to #N/A. However It is not working. See below.

```
.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
```

However when I do this I get :
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't repro this. It filters any #N/A in column E, though does not show in the custom filter screen, but is in the dropdown as having been used.

Comment: yes same - but why doesnt it show there!

Comment: #N/A is not a value - it is the result of an error of an formula.
Try using "EFERROR" in the formula that returned the #N/A and give am error message - then filter on that.
=IFERROR(<formula>,"Error Message")
You can then filter on "Error Message"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Operator:=xlAnd` at the end. It should be written as

```
.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is right as `xlAnd` is the default value for the `Operator` and so omitting it (as in the question) is the same as specifying it (as in your answer)